# Set theoretic disjoint union

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

In  [this page](http://simomaths.wordpress.com/2013/01/29/topology-disjoint-unions/) we read

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces and $Z := X \coprod Y$ be a set-theoretic disjoint union. We wish to define a topology on $Z$ in a most natural way.
>       Definition. The topology on $Z := X \coprod Y$ is defined to be:
>       $$T = \{U \coprod V : U \subseteq X, V \subseteq Y \text{ open }\}$$

My question is about the word **set-theoretic disjoint union** how is it defined and why does he call it set-theoretic does this mean that it is defined differently in other fields of mathematics other than set theory? In particular what is $X\coprod X$ and $X\coprod \emptyset$ ?

Comment: See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union#Example). So in particular, the set-theoretic disjoint union of $A$ and $B$ can be defined as the set $(A \times \{0\}) \cup (B \times \{1\}).$ Try unpacking this definition piece-by-piece. E.g. Start off with understanding the meaning of $(A \times \{0\}).$ Compute it for $A = \{a,a'\}$ for example.

Comment: Ok I see the construction. why calling it set-theoretic? I thought he means $(X\cup Y)-(X\cap Y)$. In this construction, elements of $X\coprod Y$ are couples, so $X$ is not a subset of $X\coprod Y$ in the sense of inclusion.

Comment: They probably call it set-theoretic because there is no other structure. The "topological disjoint union" is a topological space, but the "set-theoretical disjoint union" is just the set. Here, they first define "just the set" and then the topology.

Comment: Ok thanks. If $A=\{a,a'\}$ and $B=\{b,b'\}$ then $A\coprod B=\{(a,0),(a',0),(b,1),(b',1)\}$, so clearly $A$ is not a subset of $A\coprod B$

Comment: What does it mean then to say that $X$ is an open subset of $X \coprod Y$?

Comment: @palio, if a writer "defines a topology" on a set, it means they're "defining what it means for a subset of that set to be open." So the answer to your question is given by the definition of $T$. In particular, $A \subseteq X \coprod Y$ is an *open subset* iff $A$ can be expressed in the form $U \coprod V,$ where $U$ is an open subset of $X$ and $V$ is an open subset of $Y$.

Comment: By the way, the expression $(X∪Y)−(X∩Y)$ is usually called the symmetric difference of $X$ and $Y$, and often denoted $X \Delta Y$ or some such. Its a lot less fundamental than $X \coprod Y$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces, so in particular they are sets. Then (as noted in the comments) the (set-theoretic) disjoint union $X \coprod Y$ equals the set $(X \times \{0\})\cup(Y \times \{1\})$, so the set of all points of the form $(x,0)$ where $x$ ranges over $X$, and all points of the form $(y,1)$, where $y$ ranges over $Y$. So even if $X$ and $Y$ as sets would have points in common, adding the index $0$ for the first one, and $1$ for the second one, and considering sets of pairs instead, we get a "copy" of every point in $X$ and every point in $Y$, so these common points would occur two times, once with each index. 
So even $X \coprod X$ is in fact two copies of $X$, which are completely separate, and if we take a point from it, we can see by its second coordinate from which copy of $X$ the point originated. Also note that $X \coprod \emptyset = X \times \{0\}$, as there are no points with index $1$.

There are two natural functions: $j_1: X \rightarrow X \coprod Y$ and $j_2: Y \rightarrow X \coprod Y$, defined by $j_1(x) = (x,0)$ and $j_2(y) = (y,1)$. I'll denote the inverse function, that maps $(x,0)$ to $x$ by $k_1: X \times \{0\} \rightarrow X$ and the other inverse, sending $(y,1)$ to $y$ by $k_2: Y \times \{1\} \rightarrow Y$.

The natural topology (called the final topology) on $X \coprod Y$ is the *largest* topology that makes both $j_1$ and $j_2$ continuous. This means that $O \subset X \coprod Y$ is open iff both ${j_1}^{-1}[O]$ is open in $X$ and ${j_2}^{-1}[O]$ is open in $Y$.

This comes down to the same definition as yours. For $O \subset X \coprod Y$, define $O_1 = O \cap (X \times \{0\})$ and $O_2 = O \cap (Y \times \{1\})$, so $O = O_1 \cup O_2$, and note that $${j_1}^{-1}[O] = k_1[O_1] = \{x \in X: (x,0) \in O \}$$ and $${j_2}^{-1}[O] = k_2[O_2] = \{y \in Y: (y,1) \in O \}$$

So we can write $O = ({j_1}^{-1}[O]) \coprod ({j_2}^{-1}[O])$, and if $O$ is open, this is the disjoint sum of two open sets, one in $X$ and one in $Y$. So every open set in $X \coprod Y$ is of that form, which corresponds to the definition in the question.

Note that in fact $j_1$ and $j_2$ are now embeddings: $X$ is homeomorhic to $X \times \{0\} \subset X \coprod Y$ via $j_1$: it's a bijection which is (by construction) continuous and also open, as $O \subset X$ open implies $j_1[O] = O \times \{1\} = O \coprod \emptyset$ is open in $X \coprod Y$, and similarly for $j_2$.

So one often says that $X$ is a subset of $X \coprod Y$, topologically, but this is just a casual way of saying that $X$ is homeomorphically embedded (as $j_1[X] = X \times \{0\}$) in $X \coprod Y$, and again, similarly for $Y$ and $Y \times \{1\}$. The embedded copies of $X$ and $Y$ are both open in $X \coprod Y$ as well.

This construction is quite general, and can also be applied to families of spaces (not just two spaces). Again we get that every space in the family is embedded as an open, separate, copy in the total disjoint union space (or sum space, as they are also called).

Comment: Is the coproduct $X\coprod Y$ always a disconnected space? I think yes because by definition $X\coprod Y=(X\coprod \emptyset)\cup (\emptyset\coprod Y)$ so the coproduct $X\coprod Y$ is the union of two disjoint open sets  $(X\coprod \emptyset)$ and $(\emptyset\coprod Y)$ hence it is disconnected.

Comment: @palio Sure, if both spaces are non-empty (trivial condition..).

Comment: Glad to be of service. *Salutes.* Oh and I've deleted my previous comments as they're no longer relevant.